# CSS Media Query maximize elements according to width

Tags: css

I would like to build a CSS query that will respond to my width by calculating number of boxes that can fit within another box using the limit 200px.

> Display first box.
>
> If width/200px = 2, display second box
>
> If width/200px = 3, display third box

...

Something like:

```
div:not(:nth-of-type(1)){
 display:none;
}
@media only screen and (min-width:200px){
 div:nth-of-type(2){
  display:block;
 }
}
@media only screen and (min-width:400px){
 div:nth-of-type(3){
  display:block;
 }
}
@media only screen and (min-width:600px){
 div:nth-of-type(3){
  display:block;
 }
}
```

... and so forth.

Is there a way to create a single query to accomplish this?

Comment: I guess only with SASS or similar.

Comment: Is the height of those boxes fixed? If so, I'd simply put them into a container element of that same height and with `overflow:hidden` ...

Comment: But how will this work? I will have elements that are half shown. The widths are percentages. Lets say I have 4 elements, they are 25% each. Now, I want to see, if width/200px is 5, change widths to 20% with overflow:hidden. But how can I do these calculations?

Comment: try giving calc() css property a shot. You can do multiplication,division,subtraction,addition using that. Reference [https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/](https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/)

Comment: How do I pass the elements width into calc()?

Comment: if you have min-width:600px you can do like for all 3 div's to show width:calc(100% / 3) . This will set 33.3% for all 3 div's

Comment: I understand. My question is different. I want something automatic. calc(100% / (width of element / 200px))